# RTMP Streaming using ffserver

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I would like to be able to stream media content originated by eg. a file to a flash player using RTMP.

I have considered librtmp though it seems ffmpeg support rtmp more as a client than as a server, that is, it implement the push/pull models w/o a ~server~ model.

Having 'ffserver' in mind, Does it support RTMP in the above mentioned manner? is it possibe to expose H264/AAC content via RTMP using ffserver ?

Any help will B appreciated.

Nadav at Sophin

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into Red5? http://www.red5.org/

I have used CRTMP-Server and have to say its amazing, and C/C++

http://www.rtmpd.com/

it worked great for me. I used to to send a MPEG-TS stream to a flash client. for a live desktop capture application.

Basically i had a directshow filter that captured the desktop area, then fed it to a H264 encoder filter then wrapped it in a TS container and fed it via TCP to rtmpd. It worked pretty well.

Comment: Red5 is based on Java and I would rather stick to C/C++

Comment: Note for those coming in from the far future: Red5's address is now https://www.red5pro.com/red5-media-server/ and CRTMP-Server's development seems to have been stopped around 2014 — the only working link I could find was: https://github.com/dreamsxin/crtmp

Comment: I now use https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/modules/rtmp-media-streaming/ for live streaming when i self host.